# Lookup value within Date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have a list of servers (A), a start date (B), End date (C) and Project name (D) in that column order.

I want to enter a server name in another worksheet and return the project name that falls within the current date. The server could have multiple entries in the list.

Can anyone help with the formula please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Sheet1 like this:

[image]

and another sheet like this:

[image]

Then the formula in C2 could be

`{=INDEX(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$10000,MIN(IF((Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10000=A2)*(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10000<=B2)*(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$10000>=B2),ROW(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$10000),1024^2+1)))}`

This is an array formula. Enter it into the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to complete.

The formula will take the first project on the server where the given date falls into the date range between start date and end date.

If there is none, then the #REF error will be returned.

This is a German Excel. The date format is TT.MM.JJJJ (DD.MM.YYYY). But it will work with other date formats too. The only requirement is, the dates must be date values, not strings.

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

We put the server name in *Sheet2* cell **A1** *(say server2)* and in *Sheet1* we add a "helper" column...so in **E2** insert:

```
=IF(AND(B2<=TODAY(),C2>=TODAY(),A2=Sheet2!$A$1),1+MAX($E$1:E1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

The "helper" column finds the "good" rows.
Finally in *Sheet2* cell **A2** insert:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!D2:D24,MATCH(1,Sheet1!E2:E24,0))
```

to retrieve data from the first "good" row.